# How to initialize a trie data structure in C with children pointers set to NULL?

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to initialize a trie data structure in C. However, I cannot get my head around initializing all the pointers in the children[] array to NULL. Here is a part of the code I am using:

```
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node *children[27];
}
node;
```

I declared the root node using

```
node *root;
```

And tried this to set the children to NULL

```
root->children = {NULL};
```

However, this did not work and gave me an error message as follows

```
./dictionary.h:22:1: error: unknown type name 
'root' root->children = {NULL}; ^ 
./dictionary.h:22:5: error: expected identifier or '(' 
root->children = {NULL};
```

Is there another way of setting the children[] array to all NULL without using a loops?

Comment: `node *root;` is not initialization, unless it is at file scope, in which case it is `NULL`, which you cannot dereference in `root->children`.

Comment: Correction to that, what I meant is I declared not initialized, I will be using "root" to be the base of my trie data structure. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: So how *are* you initializing it?

Comment: well now that you mention I have not actually initialized it. I plan on using malloc() to initialize it since it is part of the trie data structure I will build.

Comment: Great, so initialization is easy: `node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode)); if (!newnode) {/* handle malloc failure*/} *newnode = (node){.is_word = false};`. Done.

Comment: I tried initializing using malloc(). But I got the following error "initializer element is not a compile-time constant". I think it is because I am using it as a global variable. Although, I got my mistake now basically I plan on using "root" as a pointer to the root node but not the root node itself. I will have to initialize a node structure once I put my first set of data. Thanks a lot, helped me figured out where I was going wrong.

Answer (score -1):

First if you are gonna use this variable you have to allocate memory to it, otherwise you will get Segmentation Fault.

To allocate you can use : `malloc()` from `stdlib.h`

But if you want allocate et init to NULL you can use `calloc()` from `stdlib.h`

Check the uses of calloc in manual.

Or use it like this in your case :

```
root->children = (node *) calloc(27, sizeof * root->children);
```

Comment: `NULL` is not required to be bitwise zero, so `calloc()` is not a valid way to initialize an array of nullpointers.

Comment: @EOF Could you please provide an example where this is a problem?

Comment: @Cheatah On any implementation where `NULL` is not bitwise zero, initializing a pointer with `calloc()` will cause a later test for `pointer == NULL` to evaluate to `false`, so code that needs to be protected from `NULL` (like dereferencing the pointer) will proceed and thus invoke undefined behavior (best case: crash).

Comment: @EOF Sorry for not being clear. I understand the implications when NULL is not defined as ((void*)0), but I do not know of any implementations that actually cause issues. I have never had issues using calloc for this, yet I do test my code only many architectures. I'm curious to know if there's a mythical implementation I should know about.

Comment: Let me rephrase that. If you were to do something like struct iovec *iov = calloc(1, sizeof(*iov)) please tell me about any actual implementation where iov->iov_base == NULL would evaluate to false.

Comment: @Cheatah: I don't know the bit patterns some random C implementation might choose to use for `NULL`, nor do I need to care, since I write standard-conforming code that makes no assumptions about details that are not guaranteed by the C standard.